# How to change Recycle Bin settings from the command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, vbscript, recycle-bin

Is it possible to change Recycle Bin settings from the command prompt or using VBScript?

Specifically, I want to:

- Select the "Don't move files to the Recycle Bin, Remove files immediately when deleted" option
- Clear the "Display delete confirmation dialog check box" option

Can this be done?

Comment: Which version of Windows? In Win7+ (and maybe Vista as well), the "Don't move files..." option is a per-partition setting. If you can figure out the registry changes made when those options are selected, you could do the same from the command line too. Or else look into AutoHotkey's [Send](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm) or VBScript's [SendKeys](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx) methods, which can generate the keystrokes required to replicate this.

Comment: Well this could be a possible solution. Thank you Karan. However, Im looking for automating these 2 steps with the help of batch/vbscripting. Do you have any solution with respect to this requirement.